# date range not working in vb with ms access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I need to update the rows where `pdate` (a date field) is not between the 1st and 20th day of current month and year.

I am using the code written below, but it gives an error saying "too few parameters expected 1". I am using MS Access 2007 as database.

```
cn.Execute "update water set prel = (prel + (mmt * (tx / 100))) where pdate not between 1-" & Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & Format$(Now, "YYYY") & "  and 20-" & Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & Format$(Now, "YYYY") & " "
```

Comment: Can you provide the table structure

Answer (score 6):

Your immediate issue was the missing # date delimiters, as @MicSim showed you.  However I'll suggest you consider a different approach for your WHERE clause.

Your WHERE clause, after adding the # delimiters, is similar to this (with today's date).

```
Debug.Print "WHERE pdate not between #1-" & _
    Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & Format$(Now, "YYYY") & _
    "# and #20-" & Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & _
    Format$(Now, "YYYY") & "#"
WHERE pdate not between #1-May-2011# and #20-May-2011#
```

An important issue is whether or not all your pdate values include midnight as the time component.  (Date/Time values always include a time component.)  The reason this could be significant is what should happen this month for a pdate of 5/20/2011 10:18:15 AM?  Your WHERE clause would result in an update.  But that date is still May 20th ... is that what you want?

I think there is less risk of unintended consequences with a revised WHERE clause.

```
Debug.Print "WHERE pdate < " & _
    Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "\#yyyy-mm-dd#\") & _
    " OR pdate >= " & _
    Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 21), "\#yyyy-mm-dd#\")
WHERE pdate < #2011-05-01# OR pdate >= #2011-05-21#
```

Your question is tagged vb6.  The DateSerial(), Year(), Month(), Date(), and Format() functions should all be available from the database engine's sandbox mode.  (See [Microsoft's page about sandbox mode functions](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;294698&Product=acc)).

**Edit**: Thanks to @Brian Camire for this suggestion.

```
Debug.Print "WHERE pdate < " & _
    "DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)" & _
    " OR pdate >= " & _
    "DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 21)"
```

Comment: A variation of this approach that does not rely on date literals or delimiters might be: `WHERE pdate < DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1) OR pdate >= DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 21)`

Comment: @HansUp, how do you know that the engine will execute the functions more than once in my example.  An old MSDN article [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98788) claims that that a function will be called only "one time per query if the expression does not reference a field."

Comment: @Brian Camire I didn't know, and was too lazy to use SHOWPLAN to find out.  I removed that comment and added your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for @Brian Camire's suggestion i.e. use temporal functions within the SQL code rather than construct a date literal value in VBA.

Comment: @HansUp: none, the difference was yours :) I've edited your answer and deleted my comment.

Comment: @onedaywhen Thanks for fixing up those quotes in my answer.  With your and Brian's help, I may get more points.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to delimit your dates with hashes or single quotes, depending on which database interface you are using. Use hashes (`#`) for ANSI 92 or ADO/OLEDB:

```
cn.Execute "update water set prel = (prel + (mmt * (tx / 100))) 
where pdate not between 
    #1-" & Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & Format$(Now, "YYYY") & "#  
        and #20-" & Format$(Now, "MMM") & "-" & Format$(Now, "YYYY") & "# "
```

Though, I recommend using the general format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyy-mm-dd` in this case.